How to download a file in guile?
I can't seem to find a way or an api to download a file in guile, I'm a beginner so I don't know how to add libraries, I'm using the guix package manager.
I manage to make some code like this.
(use-modules (ice-9 popen)
             (ice-9 textual-ports)
             (srfi srfi-1)
             (srfi srfi-13)
             (web client)
             (gcrypt hash)
             (email base64) ; Import the guile-email base64 module
             (ice-9 format)
             (ice-9 regex)) ; For string->utf8

(define wget (open-pipe* OPEN_READ "wget" "https://download.qemu.org/qemu-9.2.0.tar.xz" "-O" "qemu-9.2.0.tar.xz" "-nc"))
(let ((output (get-string-all wget))
      (status (close-pipe wget)))
  (display output)
  (if (zero? status)
      (display "Download successful.\n")
      (display "Download failed.\n")))

(define (calculate-sha256 filename)
  (let* ((port (open-input-pipe (string-append "sha256sum " filename)))
         (output (get-string-all port))
         (status (close-pipe port)))
    (if (zero? status)
        (car (string-split output #\space))
        "Error calculating SHA256")))

(let ((sha256sum (calculate-sha256 "qemu-9.2.0.tar.xz")))
  (format #t "SHA256: ~a~%" sha256sum))

This kind of works but of course this is just using wget, but it's not the native way to use it. How to do it natively? I feel like using bash 1 liners is not the right way to do these things.

There's no good reason for wget to be a global variable, bind it with let like the other variables.

Shouldn't need to use wget at all... Guile's (web client) library can download stuff.

Looks like you've made progress on using Guile to directly download files with http-get instead of using an external program like wget. You can also get the checksum of a file directly via Guile functions without running an external program like sha256sum. The sha256-file function in the (gcrypt hash) module takes a file name and returns a bytevector of its SHA-256 hash (There's also sha256, which takes a bytevector and hashes it). If you want to convert that to a human-readable hex string like sha256sum displays, you can use something like:
(use-modules (gcrypt hash)
             (rnrs bytevectors)
             (ice-9 format))

(define (bytevector->hex bv)
  "Return a string of hex digits representing a byte vector"
  (let ((len (bytevector-length bv)))
    (call-with-output-string
      (lambda (out)
        (do ((i 0 (+ i 1)))
            ((= i len))
          (format out "~2,'0x" (bytevector-u8-ref bv i)))))))

(define (calculate-sha256 file-name)
  "Returns the SHA-256 hash of a file, as a string of hex digits"
  (bytevector->hex (file-sha256 file-name)))


After hours of struggle, It helps using the repl to inspect what the functions return. What I didn't understand was that (values 1 2) couldn't be assigned to a variable directly.
(use-modules (web client))

(cadr (call-with-values (lambda () (http-get "https://download.qemu.org/qemu-9.2.0.tar.xz" #:decode-body? #f)) list)) ; This returns a bytevector all you have to do now is save it to a file


What does any of this have to do with downloading?

@Barmar you are right... I don't know if I should redo the question edit the answer or... just close this, it'd be a shame tho to waste the question

@Barmar Okay, I edited it so it does answer the question

You might be interested in define-values and let-values.
